# How do I set up logs with Symfony on GCP?

Tags: symfony, google-cloud-platform

I have a PHP Symfony app that I am running on the Google Cloud Platform standard environment.

When I run the server locally, I can make logs via the normal Symfony way and they show up in my console.  So for example:

`$logger->error("This is what an error looks like");`

displays in the console as

`May  7 21:38:55 |ERROR| APP    This is what an error looks like`

But when I upload to GCP, the error messages don't appear in the logs viewer.  Is there something I have to do to set up error logs for the Google Cloud Platform Console?

Comment: Have you followed all the steps from [here](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/php#running_locally_and_elsewhere) before trying to set up the error logs?